# Application of pip freeze and pip install from requirements.txt to share software version between 2 envs

Tags: python, pip

When I use pip freeze, it gives latest version of some software and older version of others as desired. For example, I have numpy 1.16 and scipy 1.6.3, so "*pip freeze > requirements.txt*" gives numpy==1.16 and scipy==1.6.3. But when I try to install from requirements "*pip install -r requirements.txt*" i get error for scipy as scipy==1.6.3 doesn't exist.
Any idea on how to handle this?

Comment: Are you using venv? Also, are you using correct version of python in virtualenv?

Comment: 2 conda envs between which I am sharing, and same python version

Comment: Can you add a full traceback?